# Sorting specific object of ArrayList

Tags: android

I have the following ArrayList hashmap:

```
 [{username=p, diff=0.0}, {username=e , diff=314.0}, {username=e ,diff=90.0}, {username=p, diff=0.0}, {username=e, diff=94.0}, {username=z, diff=92.0} , {username=z, diff=102.0}  ]
```

Implementing code below i get the whole list sorted by "diff" key:

```
Collections.sort(final_itinList,
                            new Comparator<HashMap<String, String>>() {

                                @Override
                                public int compare(HashMap<String, String> lhs,
                                        HashMap<String, String> rhs) {                                  

                                    return Double.compare(
                                            Double.parseDouble(lhs.get("diff")),
                                            Double.parseDouble(rhs.get("diff")));

                                }
                            });
```

Now i have difficulties to sort the list by "diff" key only for these objects that have username different as "p". So I want for objects that have "p" username to stay at their positions and sort the others,like...

```
[{username=p, diff=0.0}, {username=e ,diff=90.0}, {username=e , diff=314.0},  {username=p, diff=0.0}, {username=z, diff=92.0} , {username=e, diff=94.0}, {username=z, diff=102.0}  ]
```

Any quick solution; Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand well your problem, the quick solution will be to do like follows:

```
Collections.sort(final_itinList,
                        new Comparator<HashMap<String, String>>() {

                            @Override
                            public int compare(HashMap<String, String> lhs,
                                    HashMap<String, String> rhs) {                                  

                                    if( (lhs.get("username").compareTo("p")) == 0){
                                      return -1;
                                    }
                                return Double.compare(
                                        Double.parseDouble(lhs.get("diff")),
                                        Double.parseDouble(rhs.get("diff")));

                            }
                        });
```

This will check the username and if it is "p" then its value will be returned and its position will be the same as before!

Comment: I get "Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to int" at line " return (lhs.get("diff"));"

Comment: I have edited my answer! Hope this will work. Otherwise you have to return positive value instead ! If you want to sort by descending order you have to return 1 otherwise return negative value!